# Where can I use GSE-505 staples on floor i-joists

Tags: electrical, joists, cable-management

I want to run 16/3 NM cable on the i-joists near the ceiling of my unfinished basement.  I have Gardner-Bender GSE-505 NM Cable Staples made for 6/2 & 6/3 NM.  However the cental web of the i-joist is only 3/8" thick which means that the nails of the staples will protrude through the other side of the joist by 1/2".
Is this allowed? or can I attach the staples to the wider part of the i-joist?

Comment: Inquiring minds want to know what you are stringing 16/3 cable for? Is it an AC mains power application?

Comment: @MichaelKaras  You are one suspicious mod. :-)

Comment: Did you mean to say 6/3 when you said 16/3?